# How to find small claims court records?

Tags: california, small-claims-court, court-records

I'm looking for cases similar to one that I'm searching about on how to work on a defense in the Santa Clara County Small Claims Court, but I cannot the records besides the history of the process. How can I find detailed proceedings, mainly the verdicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Clerk](http://www.scscourt.org/online_services/case_info.shtml) may help but you probably need a case number to find a similar case. The library, preferably a law library or college library. In Florida I start with state statutes and then annotated state statutes and you can find references to cases listed in law reviews. The librarian can help if you have the reference. Cases in other municipalities can help but it is best to have citations of cases as nearby as possible. Google and other online resources can help.